# how to use a bootstrap template to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap template for a website:

I want to use this one: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_webpage&stacked=h

My proble is:

[image]

The template use just a little part of the screen, the footer isn't at the botom of the page.

Then I try to add: navbar-fixed-bottom class to the footer

[image]

Problem: The centers div don't go to the botom, just the footer.

Somybody knows how to do that the left, center and right div go to the botoom?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: Either provide `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` tag or fill the contents.

Comment: html{
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
}

I have tried that in my css without changes

Comment: a jsfiddle will help us

Comment: Yes, you're right: https://jsfiddle.net/5jbgwkte/

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, but we can see that the central content don't go to the footer: http://puu.sh/nEWzt/afd9451a05.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106140/discussion-between-kalpesh-singh-and-anubis).